# Solve the inequality $\left|\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right|<1$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Are these methods correct? Which one is better?

**First Method:**
$$\left|\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right|<1\Rightarrow |1-a|<|1+a|\Rightarrow(1-a)^2<(1+a)^2\Rightarrow -2a< 2a\Rightarrow 4a>0\Rightarrow \boldsymbol{a>0}$$

---

**Second Method**

$$\left|\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right|<1$$
$$-1<\frac{1-a}{1+a}<1\Rightarrow$$
$$0<\frac{2}{1+a}\,\hspace{0.25cm}   \text{and}\hspace{0.25cm} \frac{2a}{1+a}>0 $$
$$a>-1\,\hspace{0.25cm}   \text{and}\hspace{0.25cm} (a<-1  \hspace{0.25 cm}   \text{or} \hspace{0.25cm}a>0) $$
$$\boldsymbol{a>0}$$

Comment: Or the inequality states that $a$ is nearer $1$ than $-1$, so is $a>0$.

Comment: Second method definitely. Squaring often results in funny extra stuff.

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat Why?  This is just subtracting $1+a^2$ on both sides of $$1-2a+a^2 < 1+2a + a^2.$$

Comment: @GNUSupporter Oh my bad. I thought the OP jsut take the square out.

Comment: You can replace $\implies$ with $\iff$ everywhere on the first attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since none of oldest two answers addresses OP's two prompts at the beginning of the post, I post another answer for fun.

> Are these methods correct?

Yes, definitely because each implication is irrefutable.  However, they are *incomplete* because one has to find *all* $a$ satisfying the inequality.  OP has shown that

$$\left|\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right|<1 \implies a > 0,$$

but does each $a>0$ satisfy this inequality? --- This is the missing part of OP's attempt.

To complete the solution, we prove the converse of the above implication.

- $a \ge 1$: $\left|\dfrac{1-a}{1+a}\right| = \dfrac{a-1}{1+a} = 1 - \dfrac{2}{1+a} < 1$
- $0 < a < 1$: $\left|\dfrac{1-a}{1+a}\right| = \dfrac{1-a}{1+a}$.  The numerator $1-a \in (0,1)$ and the denominator $1+a > 1$, so $\dfrac{1-a}{1+a} < 1$.

> Which one is better?

The first one is more concise, and I *personally* prefer this one in this case.  However, the second one is more flexible and informative: first, it gives more information about the positivity of the fraction $\dfrac{1-a}{1+a}$ itself by decomposing it into several cases.  Second, the first method (squaring and compare the two quadratic polynomials in $a$) works well if

- either the coefficient of $a$ in both the numerator and the denominator are equal; or
- the difference of squares of both the numerator and the denominator can be factorized (in $\Bbb{R}$, by solving roots).

Otherwise, I *think* the first method would not save you work.

Comment: +1 for complete solution

Comment: Thank your so much for your answer! If $a=\sqrt{\lambda}$ for $\lambda>0\in\mathbb{R}$ can I say that the inequality is true
but not for  $a=-\sqrt{\lambda}$?

Comment: $$a = \sqrt\lambda \land \lambda > 0 \implies a > 0 \implies \left|\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right|<1 \\ a = \sqrt\lambda \land \lambda < 0 \not\implies \left|\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right|<1$$

Comment: $\lambda$ is always $\lambda >0$

Comment: @B.David My bad. I meant to say $$a = \sqrt\lambda \land \lambda > 0 \implies a > 0 \implies \left|\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right|<1 \\ a = -\sqrt\lambda \land \lambda > 0 \not\implies \left|\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right|<1.$$

Comment: Is it necessary complete my proof with your previous contribution for cases $ 0 <a <1 $ and $ a> = 1 $?

Comment: @B.David In your proof, you've just stated one-way implication $\implies$, so yes.

Comment: @B.David A related keyword is [extraneous solution](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/radical-equations-and-functions/analyzing-extraneous-solutions-of-square-root-equations/a/analyzing-extraneous-solutions-of-square-root-equations).

Answer (score 3):

#### Third method

$|1-z|<|1+z|$

Set $A=(-1,0)$ and $B=(1,0)$ and $M=(x,y)$ with $z=x+iy$

You search $M$ in the plane such that $BM<AM$, these are the points in the half-plane delimited by the perpendicular bissector of $[AB]$ (i.e. $x=0$) and closer to $B$, namely $x>0$.

---

Note: for the real case only

Just put $A=-1$ and $B=+1$ on the real line and you search for $M$ such that $BM<AM$, so $M$ is on the right of $I=0$ the middle of $[AB]$.

The condition is thus $a>0$.

Comment: Seeing the nature of the question, I'm concerned the OP might not be too comfortable with using complex number-related methods yet. It's definitely a more foolproof method once we have grasped it well but maybe not so much with someone still learning inequalities in real numbers...

Comment: +1 for both Karn Watcharasupat's concern and the effort to this answer, which *doesn't* address OP's two questions in the question body. (but the question in the title)

Comment: I was also concerned that it might be too advanced, but it expands the horizon. Although the real case can be treated similarly, I'm editing in that sense.

Comment: +1 for creative aproach

Answer (score 2):

I would always suggest sketching the graphs.

Draw the graphs $y=|1-x|$ and $y=|1+x|$ and let the graph do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Both methods are OK. I would vote for the 1.st one. It is shorther.

You could do also like this:

$$ |{2\over 1+a}-1|<1$$ so 
$$ -1<{2\over 1+a}-1<1$$ so
$$ 0<{2\over 1+a}<2$$

From the left inequality we deudce that $1+a>0$ so we have $2< 2a+2$ or $a>0$.

Comment: Both methods are *correct* but *incomplete*.  We have to show that $a \le 0$ *don't* solve the inequality to *complete* this question.

Comment: You mean that each $a>0$ does solve this inequality. $a\leq 0$ has nothing to do with the problem any more.

Comment: My bad.  You're right.